# Getting today's midnight time as UTC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query which calculates today's midnight value (UTC) as a datetime:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())+(GETDATE()-GETUTCDATE())
```

Result: `2011-11-03 19:00:00.000` (for GMT-5 on Nov. 4, 2011)

Not only that, but on occasion, it returns values like these:

```
2011-11-03 19:00:00.003
2011-11-03 19:00:00.007
2011-11-03 19:00:00.010
```

..., which are wrong!

There must be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I already answered this with a solution using DATEADD and DATEDIFF with GETDATE() and GETUTCDATE(), similar to the example given in the original question, but since then I've discovered the [datetimeoffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) data type [added in SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2009/03/31/the-death-of-datetime.aspx).  This stores a datetime along with a timezone offset.

How you use this type will depend on whether you want to change the data type of your existing data.  If you don't want to change anything, the following statement will return a datetime type with the local time of midnight:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, 
    CONVERT(date, GETDATE())), 
    DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())))
```

You could also convert any UTC time into local time using:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, 
        @myutctime, 
        DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())))
```

The datetimeoffset type is only available using SQL2008 and above.  If you need to do this with 2005 and below, you can use a solution similar to the one in the original question, but altered to account for the fact that `GETDATE() - GETUTCDATE()` is not an atomic operation and will likely involve milliseconds of difference between when the two are executed.

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, 
    DATEDIFF(minute, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), 
    CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, GETDATE())))
```

This will take the number minutes between `GETDATE()` and `GETUTCDATE()` and add them onto the local midnight time.  Unfortunately, you have to convert back from date to datetime as `DATEADD` won't work with minutes if you give it a date.  I'd suggest wrapping this into a user-defined function to make it look less verbose, e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MidnightASUTC(@dt as datetime)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN DATEADD(minute, 
        DATEDIFF(minute, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()),
        CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(date, @dt)))
END

SELECT dbo.MidnightAsUTC(GETDATE())
```

Comment: You need to reverse GETDATE() and GETUTCDATE() in the call to DATEDIFF: `DATEDIFF(hour, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE())` to get the correct result, but I tried running this about 100 times and at least got the right time.

Comment: Oops, I've reversed it.  I've also changed the answer to use DATEADD(minute...) since the hours approach wouldn't deal with the countries who are 1/2 hour offset from UTC.

Comment: I wonder if there is a performance penalty with the UDF you presented and it makes sense to make it an inline TVF that returns a 1 row / 1 column result with the value?

Comment: I've completely revised this answer now as I just came across the datetimeoffset data type, which stores a timezone offset.  Original answer has been left for anyone needing to do this before SQL2008.

Answer (score 0):

For a specific scenario like the one you've described ("today's midnight value (UTC) as a datetime"), a programmatic approach makes sense, but if you ever need to extend it to a different question (what was midnight UTC for this summer?), you may want to use a calendar table (to account for things like daylight savings time, etc).